# How to unambiguously refer to function with template overloads

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following definitions:

```
int f(int ) { return 1; } // a)

template<typename T> int f(T x) { return 2; } // b)
```

I understand that if I call `f`, e.g. `f(1)`, the non-template overload a) will be preferred, but is there a way to unambiguously refer to a)? For instance, I can use `f<int>` to refer to b) unambiguously.

As an example of why this would be useful, consider the following function:

```
template<typename Func, typename T> void print_result(Func f, T arg) 
{ 
   std::cout << f(arg) << std::endl; 
}
```

If I try to use it on `f`, e.g, `print_result(f,1)`, I get a compilation error (the compiler does not know which `f` I mean). I can use `print_result(f<int>,1)` to tell it to use b), but how do I tell it to use a) ?

I found I can use `print_result(static_cast<int (*)(int)>(f), 1)`, but this feels hacky and is cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Comment: *"I found I can use `print_result(static_cast<int (*)(int)>(f), 1)`"* That is actually the usual way to select a function of an overload set. You could also use `[](int p) { return f(p); }` or in C++1y, `[](auto&& p) -> decltype(auto) { return f(std::forward<decltype(p)>(p)); }`

Comment: Instead of the `static_cast`, you can also use an implicit conversion: `print_result<void(*)(int)>(f, 1);`

Comment: @dyp I tested it under VS2013, which uses c++11 standard, right?

Comment: @herohuyongtao VS2013 tries to be C++11 compliant in most parts (when disabling language extension); yet it's not feature-complete and is known to not comply fully (for example, dependent name lookup, and corner cases). Have you tried my live example in VS2013?

Comment: @herohuyongtao that doesn't mean it's got anything to do with c++11, `print_result(f,1)` certainly doesn't work in gcc 4.8.2 which *also* uses the c++11 standard

Comment: @dyp thank you for both your comments. Do you think there's away of writing a template to do this for you, even if it is C++1y only?

Comment: @toth Do what exactly?

Comment: @dyp and @PaulEvans, thank u guys to point out my misunderstandings here. I guess I should simply say: "`print_result(f,1)` works in VS2013 (call a) as expected)", though not sure why it is. :P

Comment: @dyp, I guess I was hoping for `pick_non_template_overload(f)` template which would work for arbitrary functions f, but I guess it's a chicken and egg situation.

Comment: Overloaded functions are supposed to perform the same task (with same/similar requirements and post-conditions). So if you need to select an overload out of an overload set that is not the best match just because a better match is a function template, there seems to be a design issue.

Comment: @dyp, I understand, I was just hoping there would be a nice way of invoking `print_result(f,1)` without using the type of `f`. Your lambda tricks achieve this, but it would be nice to be able to wrap them in a template. I guess that is not possible, so I would have to use a macro or write it out in full every time.

Answer (score 1):

use template specialization:

```
template<>
int f<int>(int x ) { return 1; } // a)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it does not really answer my question. What if I do not have the freedom to redefine the functions? I could always define a wrapper function (or lambda as dyp suggests in his comments to the question) but I was hoping there would be a neater way.

Comment: While this does solve the problem, generally one does not wish to specialize function templates (see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)